# How to download images from the Internet in a ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview

How to make a boot image from a URL in the ListView, I tried to implement with [this](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) add-on , but the error takes NullPointerExeption. I also use this [listView](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34) to display it in a horizontal format.This is my code appears when listView:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
    image_list_icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_fromlist);
   HorizontalListView listview = (HorizontalListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);


}
private static String[] dataObjects = new String[]{ "Text #1",
        "Text #2",
        "Text #3","Text #3","Text #3" };

private BaseAdapter mAdapter = new BaseAdapter() {
    ArrayList<Object> objects;
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;//
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
         return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View retval = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listview_leyout, null);
        TextView title = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(dataObjects[position%dataObjects.length]);

        try {
                if (title.getText() == "Text #1") {
                    ImageLoader imageLoader=new ImageLoader(context);
                    imageLoader.DisplayImage("http://www.learn2crack.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Untitled.png", image_list_icon);
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Ex",e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        return retval;
    }

};
```

Comment: Have a look at Picasso: http://square.github.io/picasso/, I like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you using a library called Picasso. It takes care of a lot of issues surrounding images and memory management. Its also very easy to use.

For a list view, in your adapter getView() you simply do this:

```
ImageView myImageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.myImage)

Picasso.with(context)
       .load(imageUrl)
       .into(myImageView);
```

See http://square.github.io/picasso/